# Send the entire debug console output to clipboard?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, envdte

I would like to know in **C#** or **VB.NET** if at any time I could send **all** the output that is written in the debug console of my IDE, to the clipboard.

Example Pseudo-Code in vb.net:

```
For x as integer = 0 to integer.maxvalue
    debug.writeline("test console line " & x)
next

Clipboard.SetText(Debug.Output)
```

I would like to copy all the lines of the debug console, including the messages that were written at the moment of execution, just ALL:

> WindowsApplication6.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   WindowsApplication6.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. etc... test console line 1 test console
>   line 2 test console line 3 etc...

I hope that maybe using DTE (or easier) it could be done, any ideas?

Comment: You could create a custom Trace Listener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go this way:

```
EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte2 = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.12.0");
TextSelection sel = dte2.ToolWindows.OutputWindow.OutputWindowPanes.Item("Debug").TextDocument.Selection;
sel.StartOfDocument(false);
sel.EndOfDocument(true);
Clipboard.SetText(sel.Text);
```

Comment: I didn't imagined that even using DTE it would be so easier, you made it easy, thanks for the solution. PS: Sorry for my English.

Comment: I'm asking too much if I ask you for the way to clear the debug console? I've tried with 'sel.text = ""' but does not take effect.

Comment: Try: dte2.ToolWindows.OutputWindow.OutputWindowPanes.Item("Debug").Clear();

Comment: Nope, does not clear the console (at least not in the IDE) but if I try to copy the text after "clearing" it in that way it says that the console is empty, strange.

Comment: Do you have more than one Visual Studio instance running?

Comment: Yes! haha, I'm really sorry now I've noted it in the other instance (where I've not launched the DTE instructions), thankyou again for your time